# How to pass content of image file from fileupload control to web method via javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, file-upload, webmethod

I have a problem with using binary content of file. I want to pass web method content of file. I retriev it from fileupload control on my page via javascript function getAsBinary(). But error appears in web method, when I try to create example of class Image.
So, I have the page (.aspx) with fileupload control and scriptmanager. There are three javascript function:

```
// Get image from fileupload control and pass it in webmethod
function Get_image() {
    var file_uploader = document.getElementById(file_uploader_name);
    var file_content = file_uploader.files[0].getAsBinary();
    imupcon.Get_image(file_content, OnRequestComplete, OnError);
}
// Successful execution
function OnRequestComplete(result) {alert(result);}
//Error execution
function OnError() { alert("Error!");}
```

And I have web-service with web-method:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Get_image(string file_content, string file_name) 
{
 byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(file_content);
 MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
 memStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

 //Error appears here
 System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memStream);

 memStream.Close();
 return "Hurray!";
}
```

Does any have idea, what is reason? How I can pass content of file to web method? Thanks.

Comment: i am pretty sure you can't upload a file via javascript for security purposes...

Comment: What is the content of the error?

Comment: "Illegal parameter" for Image.FromStream.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` if it's as it's already in binary. The data would be in unicode if you called `files[0].getAsText("utf-8")`. Please note that all of these methods [are now obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File) and you should use feature detection and use the [standard FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) if it is available.

Comment: Nice. So what would OP do instead? `r = new FileReader(); r.onloadend = /*...*/; r.readAsBinaryString(file_uploader.files[0].name)`?

Comment: But is it really to create example of class Image using file content, which is passed by js function?

Comment: I barely understood your question and you didn't give me much info so I just pointed out what might be causing whatever problems you are encountering.

Comment: I want to choose image file with help fileuploader, then I want to pass its content to web method and create image file on server in this web method. But when I try to create example of class Image or fill FIleStream with binary content of chosen file, error appears and it interrupts execution of my web method.